# is it possible to set the attribute as [config] with value as configForScroll using setAttribute in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working in a `angular4` project where I had used `ngx-slimscroll` which has the tag with attribute as given below

`<perfect-scrollbar [config]="configForScroll"></perfect-scrollbar>`.

Now, here my requirement is to create `<perfect-scrollbar>` element dynamically using document.createElement() function which I have done successfully.But, on setting the attribute as **[config]** I am getting error as

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createAttribute' on 'Document': The qualified name provided ('[config]') contains the invalid name-start character '['.
>   So, is there any way to set this kind of attribute as shown in below code

```
var patt = document.createAttribute("[config]");
patt.value = "configForScroll";
```

Please find me a  way to fix it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using angular's `Renderer2`?

Comment: @PardeepJain there is no use...You can't set an attribute named '[config]' using this.renderer.setAttribute(div, 'attr', 'value');

Comment: I dont see any point in dynamically adding this component's html string in angular app. Angular wont detect that change, and it will be considered as plain html only.
Like I said please see https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: @Ninjaneer are you very sure about it?

Comment: @PardeepJain Yes I am sure. 

`main.js:157843 DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '[config]' is not a valid attribute name.
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.setAttribute `

Comment: Cool !!, but There must be some way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*is it possible to set the attribute as **[config]** with value as configForScroll using setAttribute in javascript?*
**NO**

You cannot create an attribute named `'[config]'`, with special chars `'[' and ']'`. 
Doing so will raise a `INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR` exception as pointed out [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createAttribute)

> INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR if the parameter contains invalid characters for
>   XML attribute.

but you can create an attribute named 'config';

`document.createAttribute("config");//valid`

Please note that dynamically appending component tag won't work as expected. Angular will not detect those change. Your newly appended node will be considered as a plain Dom node, and not as angular component.

If your intention is to add a dynamic component then please look into to [dynamic-component-loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) and this stackoverflow answer => [How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular)